# What material might be behind my old bathroom tile?

Tags: bathroom, tile, lath-and-plaster

I am considering removing the tile in my bathroom.  The house was built in 1948, and I am concerned of what I might find behind the tile.  Can anyone tell me how they attached the tile back in those days?  Directly to a plaster wall?  I am assuming I will need to install cement board, but will I need to remove plaster and lath if it is there?

Comment: What's your location, and do you have pictures?

Comment: what you will find behind anything in an old house is always a matter of wild speculation.  There are "standards" but its really hard to say what you will find, let alone what kind of shape it will be in.

Comment: I had a house built in '48, and at one point had a vinyl window installed in the bathroom. This resulted in some tile being removed around the old wooden sill/trim. Behind the tile was regular ol' wallpaper (some ugly green stuff). Oh, and it smelled pretty foul.. like Blackbeard's nasty half-rotted teeth or something. lol

Comment: 1948, either plaster and wood lath, or plaster and Gypsum Lath, which is similar to drywall, in 18" widths, covered in plaster.  Seal all doors with plastic, wear a mask and goggles, and don't try to do it neatly.  Just go to town on that stuff.  (But watch for pipes!)

Comment: The question really cannot be answered because you won't know until you open the wall.  It could be any building material used at the time. Thus I've voted to close the question as "too broad" (which is as close as I can get to "unanswerable".